# Is it always necessary for the Sith to commit murder?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, sith

It seems that most of the characters who have turned to the dark side have committed murders around the same time i. e. Count Dooku killed Jedi Master Sifo-Dyas around the time he became Darth Tyranus, Anakin killed Count Dooku (and was an accomplice in the killing of Mace Windu) right before he became Darth Vader, and Luke, had he turned to the dark side, would have done so by killing either Darth Vader or the Emperor.

If murder really is a necessary prerequisite for becoming a Sith, whom did Darth Maul and Darth Sidious kill? (I know that Sidious killed Darth Plagueis, but he was already a Sith apprentice by then, so that couldn't have been the murder that turned him to the dark side.).

---

Note: the idea for this question came from http://www.moviemistakes.com/entry129269

Comment: Are Legends answers acceptable?

Comment: yes. And the point of this is to answer

Comment: Well you'll get more and better answers if you're specific in what you want

Comment: What I want is that is it necessary for a sith to commit murder?

Comment: There could be several different answers based on the storyline (canon or not). It would also help to not have this attitude and be so demanding.

Comment: What will you accept answers from? There are several games where the only killing you will ever do is in self-defense, if you so choose.

Comment: I think that murdering people is part of the job description (at least in canon) for a Sith :D

Answer (score 8):

## No.

Canon level: **Legends**.

[image]

[Darth Vectivus](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Darth_Vectivus) was a businessman-turned-Sith lord who maintained a strict moral code. His only interest was developing new dark side techniques, most notably Force phantoms. Though he was ruthless in his dealings with others, Vectivus had no interest in political power or violence. He died of old age, surrounded by friends and family.

Comment: Any source for point two? Like a Sith needing to meet some kill quota to keep their status?

Comment: @SonOfSam No, and actually I've found a counterexample.  Have modified my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. 
Hate drives the dark side, and hate drives to kill.

The rule of two requires a challenger to kill the existing Apprentice, and encourages the Apprentice to kill his Master.

The agenda of the Sith order is to eliminate all Jedi, by killing them, directly or indirectly.

Comment: What if there is no other apprentice? Who do they kill then?

Comment: The Jedi, of course. Or just anyone in the way, because this is the way of the Sith.

Comment: @TimSparrow The way of the Sith is **through your enemies**. Mercilessly.

Answer (score 0):

**For true Sith, only reality is power**

Any attachment, any relationship, any cause different from this is a distraction, a weakness. To achieve power, to strengthen power, true Sith would do anything necessary. And if something or someone stays in the way of power it must be destroyed, no matter how close it is to prospective Sith. In Legends, Palpatine's first act was to kill his family. Darth Malgus killed his lover Eleena Daru, because he considered her his greatest weakness. Anakin choked his wife, cut the arm of his son, and attempted to kill his former master and friend, Obi-Wan Kenobi. Darth Bane killed his father etc ...

It could be even surmised that **Dark Side requires murder of someone close to Sith** in order to grant him full power. Simply, Darth Side, by its very nature, seeks complete freedom, and any bond is considered as chain. Chain that must be broken, if necessary even by murder.